# Linux Sort Command pos2 greater than pos1

Tags: linux, sorting

The version of the UNIX `sort` command I have on my Linux distribution comes with the following option:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2] start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
```

What happens when `POS2` is greater than `POS1` in this option?